# Simulating user input in Ember component tests

Tags: jquery, ember.js, qunit

I'm trying to write tests for an ember component that simulate real user input. For example:

```
<div>
  <input class='js-input' type='text' value='{{ bar }}'> </input>
  <button class='js-save' type='submit' {{action 'save'}}>
</div>
```

My component currently uses the `change` and `keyUp` events to compute another value based on what's entered, and also to validate the input on-the-fly:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  bar: null,
  modelBar: null,

  updateBar: Ember.on('change', 'keyUp', function() {
    let bar = this.get('bar');
    if (bar.get('notValid')) {
      bar = null;
      this.set('bar', '');
    }
    this.set('modelBar', bar);
  }),

  actions: {
    save() {
      ... save stuff ...
    }
  }
});
```

So I've been using `$('.js-input').val('some new value')` to simulate this (as recommended [here](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2016/01/22/component-integration-testing-in-ember), under "Interacting with Rendered Components").

```
test('Updates a thing', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  const newState = 'a new state';

  this.set('actions.save', (newTaxes) => {
    assert.ok(true, 'save has been called');
    assert.equal(newState, this.get('modelBar'), 'model is updated correctly');
  });

  this.set('bar', 'initial state');

  this.render(hbs`
    {{my-component
      baz=baz
    }}
  `);

  this.$('.js-input').val(newState);
  this.$('.js-input').trigger('change');

  this.$('.js-save').click();     
});
```

However, when I run the test, the `change` event does not get the updated value for the input using `this.get('bar')` (although I can see it if I use `this.$('js-input').val()`). If I add an observer, I can see the observer get the updated value for the property but only *after* the custom change event fired.

I've tried wrapping things in Ember run loops and run.next loops and that hasn't helped either. Is there a way to make this work, hopefully without needing to fall back onto observers? (The component previously used an observer but some new requirements have made things more complicated.)

Comment: I might be way off, but I believe `jQuery.sendKeys`(see example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DxER9/)) plugin would do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Interesting! Something I might explore in future times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of ways to fix this, depending on your level of comfortableness. Unfortunately, neither of them involved changes simply to the tests themselves, so I'd still be happy to hear if anyone has a better solution.

One: Fix the problem jquery causes with more jquery:

```
updateBar: Ember.on('change', 'keyUp', function() {
  ... validate bar ...
  this.set('modelBar', this.get('bar') || this.$('.js-input').val());
}),
```

I'm kind of OK with this since it *should* only be for testing purposes. You can worry about `bar` having a previous value, but in my case it was always going from empty to a value so `||` was a sufficient indicator.

Two: Go back to an observer (sigh). It seems that although the `change` event does not get the updated value of `bar`, the observer does, but only *after* the change event.

```
observerBar: Ember.observer('bar', function() {
  if (!this.get('suspendObserver')) {
    this.set('suspendObserver', true);
    this.updateBar();
    this.set('suspendObserver', false);
  }
}),
```

The semaphore was necessary in my case because updateBar would clear out `bar` if the input was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because `bar` is not binded with the `<input>` element. So even if you call `this.$('.js-input').val(newState)`, `bar` will not change. Then calling `this.$('.js-input').trigger('change')` will trigger the `updateBar` but won't get your expected result.

Try this:

```
// template.hbs
<input class='js-input' type='text' value={{bar}} onchange={{action "handleChange" value="target.value"}}>

// component.js
actions: {
  handleChange(value) {
    // Your logic here -- value is the new value of your input
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add in my answer - if I add an Observer to the component, this _does_ get the updated value after the change event has fired. So it seems the value is bound successfully, it's just as if my change event fires before the Ember metal change event that would update the value.